# CustomView not rendered if I put inside a grid with RowDefinitions in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have loaded the views inside a grid as below,

```xml
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Entry x:Name="SearchTextBox"
               Grid.Row="0"
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               Placeholder="Search"
               VerticalOptions="Fill" />
        <ListView x:Name="listView"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  VerticalOptions="Fill" />
        <local:CustomListView x:Name="customView"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        </local:CustomListView >
    </Grid>
```

Out of 3 views in the above code snippet, first two views are rendered properly. But the 3rd view(custom view) not rendered. CustomViews are not rendered only if I set RowDefinition as "Auto". So, anyone please tell why the custom view is not loaded if I set "Auto".

Answer (score 0):

your `CustomListView` probably doesn't request a minimum size correctly, and as the middle row has a height of `*`, it takes all of the available space minus the minimum size requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. there is an empty space available about half the screen. first two views took only half of the screen. But if I set height explicitly, the view is rendered. So what might be the reason?

Comment: Then, it probably means the Grid doesn't take all the screen... Add `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to the `Grid` itself

Comment: I have already tried it. but no use. But one thing found was the height of my custom view has set only 22. I think thats why it did not shown in the output view. But why and how the height was set?

Comment: Any idea regarding this?